# Login help - if statement isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Ok, so I am new to the whole Javascript in HTML thing. So, I have been working on a simple login program. For some reason my function is not working. Every time I put in the correct username and password, it tells me "You entered your Username or Password incorrectly!"

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Login info stuff</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var username = document.write("<input type='text' name='Username'>");
    document.write("<br />");
    var password = document.write("<input type='password' name='Password'>");
    document.write("<br />");
    function correct(){
    if(username==="Username" & password==="Password")
    {location="blank.HTML"}
    else{alert("You entered your Username or Password incorrectly!")}
    }
    Submit = document.write("<input type='submit' value='Login' onClick='correct()'>");
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not do password verification in javascript, as an aside...

Comment: As another aside, using document.write is generally a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your comparing the username and password variables which are not the values from the textboxes. This should work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login info stuff</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write("<input type='text' name='Username' id='username'>");
            document.write("<br />");
            document.write("<input type='password' name='Password' id='password'>");
            document.write("<br />");

            function correct(){
                if(document.getElementById('username').value ==="Username" && document.getElementById('password').value === "Password")
                {
                    location="blank.HTML";
                }
                else{
                    alert("You entered your Username or Password incorrectly!")
                }
             }
             Submit = document.write("<input type='submit' value='Login' onClick='correct()'>");
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I have done here:

- Added an `id` to both fields
- When comparing the values, first obtain the DOM-element by calling `document.getElementById` and then getting the current value from the `value` property

Answer (score 0):

the `username` and `password` variables are storing the return value of document.write. They're not retrieving the values. To do this, you need to do:

```
document.write("<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" id=\"username\">");
var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
```

So your script should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<input type='text' name='Username' id='username'>");
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write("<input type='password' name='Password' id='password'>");
    document.write("<br />");


    function correct(){
        if(document.getElementById('username').value==="Username" && document.getElementById('password').value==="Password")
        {
            location="blank.HTML"
        } else {
            alert("You entered your Username or Password incorrectly!")
        }
    }

    Submit = document.write("<input type='submit' value='Login' onClick='correct()'>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

AND in JavaScript is &&

And also you need to save the values of the inputs into a variable like:

```
var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
var pwd = document.getElementById('password').value;
```

Then use this two variables into your if statement

EDIT: For use the `getElementById()` you need first to add an id to the respective input in your `document.write` line

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Login info stuff</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="myform" name="myform" action="blank.html" >
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" onclick="return correct();" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var username = document.getElementById("username"),
        password = document.getElementById("password"),
        myform = document.getElementById('myform');

    function correct() {
        if(username.value!=="username" || password.value!=="password") {
          alert("You entered your Username or Password incorrectly!");
          return false;
        } else {
          myform.submit();
        }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

re-engineered a bit
http://plnkr.co/edit/iHDlTW5726g8NqHIjz1A?p=preview